# azure ML on AKS memory and CPU parameters

Tags: azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

When specifying the memory and core for the AksWebService (deploying Azure ML as a service in AKS), do the values for cpu_cores and memory_gb apply to each replica OR all replicas combined?

```
AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(cpu_cores=1, memory_gb=1, auth_enabled=True, autoscale_enabled=True, autoscale_min_replicas=4, autoscale_max_replicas=10)
```

I am assuming its per replica but just wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

It is for combined replicas and not for the individual replica. It will be shared to entire set of replicas.

Consider the following [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/v1/how-to-deploy-azure-kubernetes-service?tabs=python) for the reference.